# I'm writing a service in Typescript and i took class based approach and creating controller object on each request is it good or bad practice?

Tags: node.js, typescript, oop, model-view-controller

In Controller

```
class myController{
  constructor(req, res, next){
    this.req = req;
    this.res = res;
    this.next = next;
  }

 // method1
 func1(){}

 func2(){}

}
```

In routes

```
router.get('/home', (req, res, next) => {
  new myController(req, res, next).func1()
})
```

While in all blogs i found singleton classes like

```
class myController {
  myfunc(req, res){
    // logic
  }
}

export new myController()
```

which is better approach? what are the demerits of creating object on each request?

Tried creating object on each request

Comment: `new myController(req, res, next).func1()` is calling a function with extra steps. Literally. I see no reason why you'd think this is any improvement over `func1(req, res, next)` which wouldn't instantiate a whole object. Or what the second approach shows and having a singleton (although that's just a OOP-warped function).

Comment: yeah I saw this in the legacy code base written by some Ruby guy just wanted to take the input on whether it has an edge over the singleton pattern if not so does it have impact on the server vitals as mentioned below  in the proposed answer like any extra memory overhead?

Comment: The extra steps *are* creating an object. Which would be essentially immediately eligible for garbage collection. One such call would probably not be a problem. Even 100 won't be. But it's still extra work that has to be done for each. And for a busy system it *will* be a problem. Most likely leading to increased load times - the system likely won't run out of memory but GC would probably run a lot and increased GC cycles (both in terms of frequency as well as work done) will eventually be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

First, approach that you're taking highly resembles Nest.js framework. So, in case you wanna write code in OOP style in production -  if possible, you probably should learn / use nest.js as it comes with a bunch of great features and you won't have to think about this stuff.

Returing to your question:

- The difference between using singleton and create a new object instance lies in memory usage. Imagine you have 100 requests per seconds. Then in the first approach you would have to create 100 objects per second and after some time you will throw them away (GC will do it for you). It might have some performance overhead, though how big it will be is hard to tell. While using singleton you use one object for every request.
- Drawback for using singleton is of course that if you have a bunch of methods that are using req / res - you would have to pass them around to each method, so I a way I see why you would store them in the object. Altough I don't see any benefits of even creating these singleton objects, why not just export your merhods as a bunch of functions? You can name your file `users.controller.ts` and export the controller function as default.